# Launch error Synergy 10.8.8 on MacBook Pro El Capitan

Tags: installation, macbook-pro

I can’t launch [Synergy](https://symless.com/synergy) 1.8.8 on my MacBook Pro (OS: El Capitan). I can lauch only version 1.7.7 and older.

It’s impossible to launch the program and I get this error.

If someone know the solution or some help?

```
Process:               Synergy [7560]
Path:                  /Applications/Synergy.app/Contents/MacOS/Synergy
Identifier:            synergy
Version:               1.8.8 (1.8.8)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Synergy [7560]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2017-06-17 03:00:43.827 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.6 (15G1510)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        F5C4428D-7AA5-7C96-981A-C50854ADD5B9


Time Awake Since Boot: 7900 seconds

System Integrity Protection: disabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00007fbdc0800000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
```

Comment: the all crash report is real needed here, would you mind posting it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) isn’t enabled on your machine.

To confirm that, you can run the command `csrutil status` which would probably return `disabled` status.

For more info, [go to these official Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html).

Which provides this steps to enable SIP:

1. Boot to Recovery OS by restarting your machine and holding down the <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> keys at startup.
2. Launch Terminal from the Utilities menu.
3. Enter the following command:
   `csrutil enable`
4. Reboot the system and verify if SIP is enable by command: `csrutil status`

Which should return:

```
System Integrity Protection status: enabled
```

Comment: Well, that will switch SIP back on, but what makes you think SIP is the problem?

Comment: @Tetsujin my bad! i get it now, i just rushed to turning SIP on as i once to had a problem with an application that needs SIP to be on in order to work, i did some research and find out this problem is some how caused by `synenergy` corrupted key. BTW maybe it will be easy to find out the really problem if @Neck will also post the `Termination Reason` and i will edit the answer correspondingly.